# Initiator of request - Burp Suite

Tags: android, emulation, traffic, burp

I am analyizing the traffic of an Android application via the Burp Suite and the emulator of Android Studio.

How can I find out the initiating App of a request? I would like to know if a request is started by my app or another app or by the system.

Thanks in advance!

I successfully started the emulator and the Burp Suite. I can see the traffic but I do not know where the requests Comes from.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to recognise from which request comes from which application (the only thing you probably you would be able to get is the sender (the phone/emulator itself, the receiver/target (the server which the data is requested from) and maybe some metadata (auth etc., which probably will be encrypted))

Comment: @JustSightseeing Ok, thx. How can I analyze the outgoing requests when using android Studio and inporting the apk?

Comment: Using the Network Inspector (https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/network-profiler)

Comment: I will post this as an answer, just for you to be able to mark this question as closed with an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments:

> I don't think you will be able to recognise from which request comes from which application (the only thing you probably you would be able to get is the sender (the phone/emulator itself, the receiver/target (the server which the data is requested from) and maybe some metadata (auth etc., which probably will be encrypted))

You can use the network inspector in android studio if you manage to import the app into it tho